# War Creation Using Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am developing Spring Boot with Angular application. I have my angular project under src/main/webapp folder.
I modified the angular.json to output the build files to **resources/static** folder.
Until here, the files are generated perfectly.
But when I am generating the war file using gradle, I can see all the **src** and **node_modules** folder from webapp folder in the generated war.

Can anyone assist on how to exclude these files in creating the war by copying the build files to resources.static folder.

Answer (score 0):

This guy has it solved https://github.com/indrekots/static-content-demo

It's just as you need, I think